# Screenshots with VLC are blue-ish. Why?

Tags: vlc-media-player, screenshot

I'm using VLC to make some screenshot but, while playing the video the image is clear, when I take a screenshot (I'm using the snapshot tool inside VLC), here's the result:

[image: blue-ish image in VLC]

What am I doing wrong? If you need infos about the video (codec etc..) just tell me how to get them and I will post them.

**EDIT #1**

Here's codec information

[image]

**EDIT #2**

VLC Version: 1.1.8

Comment: smells like [Pandoran](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Pandora) ambiance ;)

Comment: Can you post what you see in the Tools->Codec Information dialog?

Comment: @heavyd: is that what you need?

Comment: How are you taking the screenshots?  Print-screen key then paste into a program?  It might be the program you are saveing the screenshot to does not support the pixel format that is being stored on the clipboard.  Have you tried using Paint.NET to paste the images in?

Comment: Are you using VLC's snapshot function? (I think it's Ctrl+Alt+S) If not, the cause of this problem is probably the fact that VLC renders its frames directly to the video card (overlay) for better performance. So using a screenshot tool might not work, I guess

Comment: I'm using the "take a snapshot" tool inside vlc.

Comment: @dierre, yep that's what I was looking for.  One more question, what version are you running?

Comment: @heavyd: the version is 1.1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a [long standing bug](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/2546) in VLC in handling RV24 video that might be the root of your problem.  I would suggest using a different input format if you can.

To find out if you can change the input format open the messages window from the Tools menu and turn the verbosity up to 2.  Now open your stream and once it starts playing stop it.  Go back through the log messages a look for something along the lines of:

```
dshow debug: EnumDeviceCaps: input pin accepts chroma: RV24
```

If you see anything besides RV24 (maybe YUY2) , then you should be able to click on the "Advanced Options" when you setup the stream and set the "Video input chroma format" to one of the other values listed in the`EnumDeviceCaps`.  If it doesn't give you any other options, you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution did the job for me:
tools -> preferences -> video -> video snapshots (at the bottom) -> format: .jpeg -> save.

Comment: Could you possibly edit your answer to include the version of VLC and your OS? The other answer mentions a bug that has long since been closed. This information might help others researching similar issues.

Comment: @Burgi I use Fedora 24 and I got the same problem. I solved by saving screenshots in tiff format. `vlc-3.0.0-0.5.fc24.x86_64`